# Can not send data to another module in VIPER

Tags: objective-c, viper-architecture

How can i send data from Module A to Module B in VIPER? I use router A, which has information for Module B, and try to send this information to view controller B or presenter B. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Have you read the "Book of VIPER" by Rambler?

Answer (score 7):

In that case my workflow is:

1. Usually the user interface (`view`) in module A launches an event that triggers the module B.
2. The event reaches the `presenter` in module A. The `presenter` knows it has to change module and notifies `wireframe` who knows how to make the change.
3. The `wireframe` in module A notifies to `wireframe` in module B. In this call sends all data needed
4. The `wireframe` in module B continues its normal execution, transferring the information to the `presenter`

> `wireframe` in module A must know `wireframe` B

Answer (score 5):

Use delegates to send data between VIPER modules:

```
// 1. Declare which messages can be sent to the delegate

// ProductScreenDelegate.swift
protocol ProductScreenDelegate {
//Add arguments if you need to send some information
    func onProductScreenDismissed()
    func onProductSelected(_ product: Product?)
}

// 2. Call the delegate when you need to send him a message

// ProductPresenter.swift
class ProductPresenter {

    // MARK: Properties
    weak var view: ProductView?
    var router: ProductWireframe?
    var interactor: ProductUseCase?
    var delegate: ProductScreenDelegate?
}

extension ProductPresenter: ProductPresentation {

    //View tells Presenter that view disappeared
    func onViewDidDisappear() {

        //Presenter tells its delegate that the screen was dismissed
        delegate?.onProductScreenDismissed()
    }
}

// 3. Implement the delegate protocol to do something when you receive the message

// ScannerPresenter.swift
class ScannerPresenter: ProductScreenDelegate {

    //Presenter receives the message from the sender
    func onProductScreenDismissed() {

        //Presenter tells view what to do once product screen was dismissed
        view?.startScanning()
    }
    ...
}

// 4. Link the delegate from the Product presenter in order to proper initialize it

// File ScannerRouter.swift
class ProductRouter {

    static func setupModule(delegate: ProductScreenDelegate?) -> ProductViewController {
        ...
        let presenter = ScannerPresenter()

        presenter.view = view
        presenter.interactor = interactor
        presenter.router = router
        presenter.delegate = delegate // Add this line to link the delegate
        ...
        }
}
```

For more tips, check this post https://www.ckl.io/blog/best-practices-viper-architecture/

Answer (score 3):

Does ***wireframe*** have reference to presenter? 
[This version of VIPER which i use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUP2f.png)

The ***router*** knows about another module and tells ***view*** to open it. ***Assembly*** combines all parts of module.